# Extremely slow Rails webpacker compile times with hundreds of thousands of assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm working on a project that includes pictures for a google maps overlay and consequently contains around 750k image assets. This project uses rails 6 and webpacker, and after copying in all the files to the correct directory the webpage load times increase to the point of hours. The assets are located in /app/assets/images/.

So far I've tried using rails assets:precompile, which after a night of compiling didn't finish.
An odd thing is this only happens after a server restart. If I copy in the files while the server is running then everything behaves and performs fine.

What can I do to fix this? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding where the images should go and how webpacker should fit in?

Thanks

Comment: That's a *lot* of image assets. Why so many? Can't they be packaged up some other way? This is where having a separate project to manage that, or an object store (e.g. AWS S3), or static site (e.g. GitHub Pages) can help immensely.

Comment: If you package all of those into one pack I'm going to presume that pack becomes gigantic. It seems unlikely that a single user would need 100% of the images, so you're forcing a huge download that's not really going to be utilized effectively. It's worth chunking this up. A lot.

Comment: Not all images are needed to be loaded at once, and the reason for that many is it's a tileset for drone imagery being overlaid on a map. It went through some post processing and that was the result.

Comment: What @tadman said host these in some form of cloud storage and retrieve them on demand I cannot imagine you need to overlay even 100 images at a time let alone 750k

Comment: Shipping the *entire* set of photos to the client sounds like a huge problem. Do you want your app to download gigabytes of webpack data before it boots? Probably not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately wound up not including the files in development. In production we use apache, and that serves the large number of files without any problem.